# Git Re-Clone an existing repository from origin?

Tags: git

So I've been running into some issues when I try to pull down changes from a bit bucket repo, I believe its something about the permissions on a shared folder that I do not have access to change. I have no problems editing or moving files or anything, and I can clone a new repository with no problem, and I can delete my existing repo and then clone it again. When I try to pull I get an "Unable to write new index file"

Is it possible to just re-clone my local repo from its origin?